# Which is the right way to use bluebird with mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, bluebird

From bluebird doc:

```
// Mongoose
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"));
```

From mongoose doc:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
// Use bluebird
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is two discussions

- [`Ability to specify which ES6 promises library mongoose uses`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2688)
- [use Q.js](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1699)

> People asked for promises support and Mongoose is quite a mature library now over 4 years old- mpromise was chosen because it looked like a good way to add promise support at a time.

So we can find this usage from bluebird,

```
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"));
```

> `mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');` will make mongoose use native promises. You should be able to use any ES6 promise constructor though, but right now we only test with native, bluebird, and Q

So both of them are OK.

Comment: Following that discussion, I'm not clear on one thing. Does doing `mongoose.Promise=require('bluebird')` make mongoose api promise compatible? Could I do `Model.findOne(…).then(…)`? Or would you still need to `promisifyAll(mongoose)`?

Comment: @laggingreflex, after `mongoose.Promise=require('bluebird')` it could make mongoose api compatible, No need to `promisifyAll(mongoose)`, and `Model.findOne(…).then(…)` works well, as least it works well in my project with some codes like that. I guess it may be issue with some APIs, IMHO.